# How to map color names with their HEX to make a conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I have the dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID001', 'ID002', 'ID003', 'ID004', 'ID005', 'ID006'],
                   'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Purple']})

      ID   Color
0  ID001     Red
1  ID002   Green
2  ID003    Blue
3  ID004   Green
4  ID005  Yellow
5  ID006  Purple
```

And I'm trying to get this kind of Excel spreadsheet output :

[image]

By using [**`xlsxwriter`**](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html), the code below that I made has no effect :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('TestColor_SpreadSheet.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='TestWorksheet')

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['TestWorksheet']

    format_red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#FF0000'})

    worksheet.conditional_format('B1:B7', {'type': 'cell',
                                        'criteria': '=',
                                        'value': "Red",
                                        'format': format_red})
```

Do you have any propositions please on how to do this conditional formatting in [**`xlsxwriter`**](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html) or maybe even with pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib can convert color names to RGB and hex values for you

```
>>> from matplotlib import colors
>>> 
>>> colors.to_rgb('blue')
(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>>> 
>>> colors.to_hex('blue')
'#0000ff'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I posted an answer with the full code inspired by your proposition ;).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jprebys's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74276809/16120011) and @Sergey's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72748574/16120011), I ended up with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import colors

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID001', 'ID002', 'ID003', 'ID004', 'ID005', 'ID006'],
                   'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Purple']})

# ---- Retrieving HEXes with matplotlib

def to_hex(df):
    return colors.to_hex(df["Color"])

df["HEX"] = df.apply(to_hex, axis=1)

# ---- Creating a dictionary of color names and their HEX

df_colors  = df.loc[:, ["Color", "HEX"]].drop_duplicates()
dico_colors = dict(zip(df_colors["Color"], df_colors["HEX"]))

df.drop(columns="HEX", inplace=True)

# --- Formatting the Excel Spreadsheet

with pd.ExcelWriter('TestColor_SpreadSheet.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='TestWorksheet')
    
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['TestWorksheet']
    
    dico_format = {}
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        key = row['Color']
        dico_format['bg_color'] = dico_colors[key]
        cell_format = workbook.add_format(dico_format)
        worksheet.write(idx+1, 1, key, cell_format)
```

**Note** : `'bg_color'` stands for *Background color* as per the official [**documentation**](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html).

##### # Outupt (in Excel):

[image]